# ¿Qué son los "teams" en Laravel?

Tags: laravel-8

Estoy probando [Laravel JetStream](https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/introduction.html)

Se puede instalar con la opción de usar "teams" o no. Estoy leyendo la doc oficial, traduzco teams, como equipos, no se exactamente a que se refiere... si son grupos de usuarios y privilegios, u otra cosa distinta...

¿Cuál es la definición en español?

Comment: Los teams son basicamente "grupos" de usuarios, en los que un usuario puede pertenecer a diferentes grupos, similar a los grupos de usuarios de linux. Aquí tienes la [documentación](https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/features/teams.html) de los teams.

Comment: @Benito-B, por lo que veo dentro de cada *team* o grupo los usuarios adoptan diferentes roles y permisos. Por aclararnos, una aplicación sin *teams*, es como si tuviera 1 solo *team* en cuanto a la jerarquía de todos los usuarios del sistema, ¿correcto?

Comment: Una instalación de Laravel 8 sin el soporte para teams no crea equipos privados ni tampoco le da al usuario la posibilidad de crear nuevos así como de unir o unirse a los ya existentes